# Entry field in Python GUI cannot be empty

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I have this code, that get username and password. but the problem is even if the entry field remain empty, it still can run. I want to make it if the entry field is empty, the user must enter the username and password again.

```
from Tkinter import *
def onclick():
pass

import tkMessageBox

root = Tk() 

root.title("Pantai Hospital")
root.geometry("200x200") 
L1 = Label(root, text='Welcome to Pantai Hospital!')
L1.pack()

def messageWindow1():
   win = Toplevel()
   win.geometry("300x300") 
   frame1 = Frame(win)
   frame1.pack()

   frame2 = Frame (win)
   frame2.pack()

   frame3 = Frame (win)
   frame3.pack() 

   L2 = "Login"
   Label(frame1, text = L2).pack()

   L3 = Label(frame2, text = "Username:")
   L3.pack( side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 10)
   username = StringVar()
   E1 = Entry(frame2, textvariable = username, width = 40)
   E1.pack( side = LEFT)

   L4 = Label(frame3, text = "Password:")
   L4.pack( side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 10)
   password = StringVar()
   E2 = Entry(frame3, textvariable =  password, show = "*", width = 40)
   E2.pack( side = LEFT ) 

validuser = ["yeojin" , "1234"]
v = 0
 def loginCallBack() :
      counter = 0
    if username.get() and password.get() in validuser :
       tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Welcome!" , "You are successfully logged on.")
    else :
        tkMessageBox.showinfo ("Login error", "please try again.") 
        while (counter < 3):
            if username.get() and password.get() in validuser:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Welcome!" , "You are successfully logged on." )
            else :
                counter = counter + 1

B3 = Button ( win, text = "Login", command = loginCallBack)
B3.pack()
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
counter = 0

def loginCallBack() :
    global counter
    if username.get() == "" or password.get() == "":
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Login error", "Username and password fields can not be empty.")
    elif username.get() == validuser[0] and password.get() == validuser[1]:
       tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Welcome!" , "You are successfully logged on.")
    else :
        if counter < 3:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo ("Login error", "Please try again.") 
            counter += 1
        else:
            #do whatever you want after 3 failed attempts
            root.destroy()
```

Your problem is in this line:

`if username.get() and password.get() in validuser:`

Python interpreter sees that line as

`if (username.get()) and (password.get() in validuser)`

So when you are chaining conditions you need to check them individually. Something like

`if username.get() in validuser and password.get() in validuser`.

Of couse if you do that user can log in by entering both fields "1234" or "yeojin" so you should specifically check values like this.

`if username.get() == validuser[0] and password.get() == validuser[1]`

Also, to catch empty entry fields you can add another condition to `loginCallBack()`. If one of those entry fields is empty, you can pop up a message and do nothing else.

Other than that, using while loop, is not a good idea since there is already an infinite loop there(the mainloop).
You can create  a global counter *outside* of your callback and on every failed attempt increment that value and every click check that value if it is less than 3 or not.